# Jquery - Why does using this on selector not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I trying to dropdown a div using jquery with css. On my page I have a drop down and I use .click to toggleClass.

This is the html and jquery

```
<div class="service">
    <div class="service-btn">
        <h3>head</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="service-info">
        some text
    </div>
</div>

$('.btn-service').click(function() {
    $('.service-info', this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

For some reason this does not work. Even though earlier on the page I use

```
<li class="btn-dropdown">
    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

$('.btn-dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.nav-dropdown', this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

and this does work. When I say it works I mean that the class is toggled and added to the html tag.

The one that doesnt work does not add/remove the class with toggleClass. Nothing happens at all and the jquery never gets triggerd by click.

The jquery part of the code is the same with the exception of class names so why doesn't the service code work like the dropdown code. Is it the html?

Comment: There is no `.btn-dropdown` in your first example, hence jQuery cannot bind the click event handler.

Comment: Debugging pro tip: Putting in the line `console.log(
$('.btn-dropdown').length)` would have let you know there no matches to the selector.

Comment: sry that was a actually a typo. the first button is .service-btn. It doesnt work even when the classes match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ".btn-dropdown" like Felix Kling said.

```
"<div class="service">" should be changed to "<div class="btn-dropdown">
    <div class="service-btn">
        <h3>head</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="service-info">
        some text
    </div>
</div>

$('.btn-dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.service-info', this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

the "click" function responds to the preceding selector element. You could also replace `"$('.btn-dropdown').click" with "$('.service').click"` it should return a similar result

Comment: Im sorry I messed up the code when I retyped it. The first button is in fact .service-btn and it does match the class in the toggle. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah I see! 'click function responds to the preceding selector element'. So the element I want to toggleClass on must be child of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help you .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="service">
            <div class="service-btn">
                <h3>head</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="service-info">
                some text
            </div>
        </div>        
        <li class="btn-dropdown">
            <div class="btn-dropdownLi">
                <h3>LI Toggle</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>        
        <script>
        $('.service-btn').click(function() {
            $('.service-info').toggle('');
        });        
        $('.btn-dropdownLi').click(function() {
            $('.nav-dropdown').toggle('');
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```